# print won't print in if statement of my python3.6 code

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I'm just learning python, complete newbie to coding. Below (in the image) is some simple code that I did after doing an exercise in "Learning Python the Hard Way 3".
What I can't seem to solve is why my "print" after the "if" statements won't print. Any suggestions?

[simple python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjoxL.png)

Comment: We normally require you to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of code, the code should be included in your question for us to easily replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's in line 12. You got the user's input in line 10, and set it to the variable snow. When it gets to line 12, it prompts you again because you call input(prompt) again. Rather, your code should be like `if snow == "No":`, then it will use your response without prompting you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asking for input and storing it in the variable `snow`. Then your `if` statement is asking for input again.

Change line 12 to use the `snow` variable: `if snow == "No":`.